# Why do TDateTime calculations involve variants?

Tags: c++builder, variant, tdatetime

Simple sample code below, with the generated assembler. I'm surprised that the generated code involves variants. The Delphi equivalent certainly doesn't.

```
TDateTime t1;
TDateTime t2;
...
int x =  2 * (t2 - t1);
```

Generated code.

```
Unit23.cpp.18: int x =  2 * (t2 - t1);
00401814 66C745C82400     mov word ptr [ebp-$38],$0024
0040181A 8D45DC           lea eax,[ebp-$24]
0040181D E852180000       call $00403074
00401822 50               push eax
00401823 FF45D4           inc dword ptr [ebp-$2c]
00401826 8D55A8           lea edx,[ebp-$58]
00401829 8D45A0           lea eax,[ebp-$60]
0040182C E8FB000000       call System::TDateTime::operator -(const System::TDateTime &)
00401831 DD5D94           fstp qword ptr [ebp-$6c]
00401834 8D5594           lea edx,[ebp-$6c]
00401837 8D45EC           lea eax,[ebp-$14]
0040183A E8F1180000       call $00403130
0040183F FF45D4           inc dword ptr [ebp-$2c]
00401842 8D55EC           lea edx,[ebp-$14]
00401845 B802000000       mov eax,$00000002
0040184A 59               pop ecx
***
0040184B E808010000       call System::operator *(int,const System::Variant &)
***
00401850 8D45DC           lea eax,[ebp-$24]
00401853 E8001A0000       call $00403258
00401858 89459C           mov [ebp-$64],eax
0040185B FF4DD4           dec dword ptr [ebp-$2c]
0040185E 8D45DC           lea eax,[ebp-$24]
00401861 BA02000000       mov edx,$00000002
00401866 E811190000       call $0040317c
0040186B FF4DD4           dec dword ptr [ebp-$2c]
0040186E 8D45EC           lea eax,[ebp-$14]
00401871 BA02000000       mov edx,$00000002
00401876 E801190000       call $0040317c
0040187B 66C745C81800     mov word ptr [ebp-$38],$0018
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that the result of t2 - t1 is **TDateTime** and no operator has been defined to multiply int with TDateTime, In this circumstance compiler applies unwanted conversions/casts. Both of operands have been casted to Variant and this global scope operator is called (int on left):

```
Variant __fastcall operator *(int lhs, const Variant& rhs)
{
    return Variant(lhs).operator *(rhs);
}
```

I recommend you to prevent unwanted casts by specifing operand type, thus you should change the expression as:

```
int x =  2 * (t2 - t1).Val;
```

or

```
int x =  2 * (int)(t2 - t1);
```

or

```
int x =  2 * (t2.Val - t1.Val); // best, minimum assembly is generated
```